# Converting an ambiguous CFG to a non-ambiguous CFG

Tags: grammar

I have the grammar:

```
S -> aSb | bSa | SS | epsilon
```

and I want to generate an unambiguous version.

I tried layering but only get to this, which is not unambiguous I don't believe, because the rules A -> aC and A -> AA are both possible for some inputs:

```
S -> A | epsilon

A -> aC | bD | AA

C -> Cb | b

D -> Da | a
```

Comment: Those two grammars aren’t even equivalent. For example, once I’m in C, I can produce an infinite number of `b`s, although `a`s and `b` should always come in pairs by the original grammar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
S  -> aSb | bSa | SS | ϵ
```

If I’m not completely wrong here, the only issue here is the left recursion of S, so if you remove that, you should be fine:

```
S  -> S' S'
S' -> aSb | bSa | ϵ
```

This should also eliminate ambiguity.

An alternative solution could be this:

```
S  -> aSbS | bSaS | ϵ
```

Comment: I don't think this is entirely unambiguous. Take input epsilon. We can follow the rule S -> epsilon, or we can follow S -> S'S' -> epsilon S' -> epsilon epsilon = epsilon.

Comment: Hmm, you might be right there. You can just remove the epsilon from `S` though to fix that. I also added another solution to my answer which might be equivalent?